# Laravel eloquent destroy redirect issue

Tags: laravel, redirect, eloquent, hosting

I am struggling in solving the destroy issue for the past couple of days.
It works well on local, but when I upload it to the hosting server (siteground), it doesn't work properly.
When I delete a certain item, it redirects to the "https://mydoamin/undefined". The item has already removed.

This is a blade file with delete action in your code.

```
<a class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"  onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('delete_form_{{$position->id}}').submit();">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                                </a>
                                <form id="delete_form_{{$position->id}}" action="{{ route('position.destroy', $position->id)}}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('delete')
                                </form>
```

This is a route.

```
Route::resource('position', 'PositionController');
```

This is a controller.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Position::destroy($id);
    return redirect()->route('position.index')->with('message', 'It has been deleted successfully.');
}
```

I would appreciate that someone has some idea and let me know about the solution.

Comment: are you caching your route? try `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to optimize the cache with the above command, but it looks the same.

Comment: But it works on localhost. This error only occurs on the hosting server.

Comment: can you inspect in developer console the actual response from the server?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/s44e23

Comment: Could be that localhost server is run from root (i.e. `php artisan serve`) and remote online server's virtual host is set to be run from public. I'd check differences there if so.